# Kernel of bipartite linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let V be a vector space. A linear map T : V →V is said to be bipartite if there are subspaces W1, W2 ⊂ V such that V = W1 ⊕W2 (internal direct sum). and such that T(W1) ⊂ W2 and T(W2) ⊂ W1. Let T be
bipartite with respect to the decomposition V = W1 ⊕W2. Show that dimKerT ≥ |dimW1 -dimW2|.

I have proved that the bases for W1 and W2 should be the bases for V. But I do not know how to convert this conclusion to the objective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume WLOG that $\dim (W_1)\geq \dim (W_2)$ then we can look at the restriction of the map $T$ to $W_1$. Now by the rank nullity theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem used on the restriction we have that $$\dim(W_1)=\dim(\ker(T|_{W_1}))+\dim(Im(T|_{W_1}))$$ But as $V$ is bipartite we get by the condition on $T$ that $Im(T|_{W_1})\subset W_2$ hence $\dim(W_1)=\dim(\ker(T|_{W_1}))+\dim(Im(T|_{W_1}))\leq \dim(\ker(T|_{W_1}))+\dim (W_2)\leq \dim(\ker(T))+\dim(W_2) \Leftrightarrow \dim(\ker(T))\geq \dim(W_1)-\dim(W_2)$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Your are welcome :)